# Python: Execute scp, stdin for password not working

Tags: python, passwords, stdin, popen, scp

I'm trying the following

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
Popen(["scp", "-B","user@url:file", "."], stdin=PIPE, shell=False).communicate(input="password")
```

But I still get the password promt, and no password is sent.
I know I can use scp with keys, but this is not what I need.

Any help?

Comment: Answers to this related question may help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387731/use-subprocess-to-send-a-password)

Comment: This question might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250283/how-to-scp-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**scp** interacts with the terminal directly, rather than reading from **STDIN**, You can't pass the password via a pipe, it security matter for scp and it's the same for sftp, ssh.

you can try it in you terminal like this (and it will not work):

```
echo "password" | scp me@localhost:test .
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, scp (and ssh) read the password directly from the console instead of stdin, so using subprocess to send the password will not work.  You can use [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) instead - see the docs and numerous examples for how to do this.