# Python subprocess that asks for password

Tags: python, scp

I'd like to call `scp` from Python script. `subprocess.call` doesn't work because `scp` asks for password. Someone asked same question last [year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387731/use-subprocess-to-send-a-password) and the answer was to use Pexpect.

Is there some quick hack for this that doesn't involve installing Pexpect library?

I tried `echo password | scp ...` and it still asks for password

**Answer update**:

Making key-pair got the job done, following instructions [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/06/perform-ssh-and-scp-without-entering-password-on-openssh/)

Comment: You definitely need Pexpect, it's really the only way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you don't want to use Pexpect, why not use a key pair?