# Not able to pass password for password prompt

Tags: python

I have the following code ,line "call("ectool --server=commander.company.com login username",shell=True)" prompts for a password,how do I pass the
password to the shell?

```
from subprocess import call

def main():
    list = ['741679','741477']
    call("export COMMANDER_SERVER=commander.company.com" ,shell=True)
    call("ectool --server=commander.company.com login username",shell=True)
    #need to pass password

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [expect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) library for python. This library allows you to write a "script" which specifies how your program should respond to the subprocess, based on prompts.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('ectool --server=commander.company.com login username')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('<supersecretpassword>')
```

---

*note: credit where it's due - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387731/use-subprocess-to-send-a-password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387731/use-subprocess-to-send-a-password_)*

Comment: I don't know. But if you find a solution like that, you can submit it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: how to install pexpect,  File "test_ectool.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pexpect
ImportError: No module named pexpect

Comment: sudo -E pip install pexpect

Comment: its not working,i dont think the command is spawning..how to run it as a shell?

Comment: Are you on mac or linux? Ubuntu has a `python-pexpect` package you can install with `apt-get`.