# Python popen() insert password when asked for

Tags: python, stdout, stdin, popen

I develop a python gui for a c program. The Program asks for two passwords. 
How can I wait for the password promt and then insert the password in code?

At the moment I try to do this via:

```
subprocess.popen.communicate(input)
```

But that doesn't work as the program asks for the password in the shell again.

Just for your understanding here is the flow of the program:

- shell: execute the program with some parameters
- stdout: "please insert pw 1"
- stdin: pw1
- stdout: "please insert pw 2"
- stdin: pw2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to provide password to a process with subprocess \[python\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189348/unable-to-provide-password-to-a-process-with-subprocess-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should considerate using another library : [Pexpect](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

> Pexpect is a pure Python module for spawning child applications;
>   controlling them; and responding to expected patterns in their output.
>   Pexpect works like Don Libes’ Expect. Pexpect allows your script to
>   spawn a child application and control it as if a human were typing
>   commands.

Here is a sample of code to give a username and password when connecting to FTP server :

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
child.expect('Name .*: ')
child.sendline('bob')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('thisisnotasecurepassword')
```

Comment: Nice, have a great day ;)