# Using subprocess with fab in python

Tags: python, fabric

I am new to Python and trying to use subprocess for running a script inside another script.  I have found several resources online that were very close but unfortunately couldn't help me run my code without error yet.

Here is what I want to do: 
In my script1 (main script), I am creating a fabfile.py (script2). This script2 or fabfile.py needs to be executed from script1. After some research, I figured out that execfile and os.systems are not good options therefore I decided to use subprocess. (Reference: [How can I make one python file run another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974849/how-can-i-make-one-python-file-run-another))

Here is what I am doing but not working:

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")
import os
os.getcwd() 
desk = "/Desktop"
path = str(home)+str(desk)
f = open("fabfile.py","w") # Creating a fabfile.py
f.write("from fabric.api import run \ndef task1(): \n    run('ls')")
import subprocess
host = raw_input("Enter the host IP with username e.g. root@10.0.0.2:")
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['fab', '-f path/fabfile.py', '-H host'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p1.communicate()
print output
```

Note: In the line

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['fab', '-f path/fabfile.py', '-H host'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I have tried MANY different formats - quote and double quotes placement, `$` and `%` for variable etc etc. but none seem to be working. Any idea what am I doing wrong? 
The examples I see are usually simple with no variables being used as arguments.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Consider using fabrics execute methode: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't specify python variables in string
2. Separate flags

   ```
   p1 = subprocess.Popen(['fab', '-f', path+'/fabfile.py', '-H', host],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   ```
3. When joining paths, its a better idea to use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

   ```
   fab_file = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", 'fabfile.py')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there is one more issue, that is, inputing password. Because even after correcting variable issue, I am getting error (a different one). I think instead of using fab, I can simply do,

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 
host = raw_input("Enter the host IP with user e.g. root@10.0.0.2:") 
conn1 = Popen(['ssh',host,'ls'], stdin=PIPE) 
conn1.communicate('password')
```

Reference: [Use subprocess to send a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387731/use-subprocess-to-send-a-password)

Comment: please open another question it is all different and look at the answer of this question

Answer (score 0):

Code might not be 100% correct, but something like this should work

```
import fabric.api as api
from path.my-other-fabfile import my_ssh_connection_blah

api.ls()
host = raw_input("Enter the host IP with username e.g. root@10.0.0.2:")

env['host']=host
my_ssh_connection_blah()
```

Answer (score -1):

Python won't interpolate the variables `path` and `host` for you, you need to do it explicitly.

Change:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['fab', '-f path/fabfile.py', '-H host'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

to:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['fab', '-f ' + path + '/fabfile.py', '-H ' + host],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: `'-f'` and `path + '/fabfile.py'` as well as `'-H'` and `host` should be different parameters