# Python subprocess: how to send a password (rclone configuration)

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to use [rlcone](https://rclone.org/) inside python.
If I don't encrypt my rclone config with a password, then I can simply do this:

```
import subprocess 
process = subprocess.Popen(["rclone", "listremotes"], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()
print(output)
```

But I want to protect my Rclone config with a password, so I need a way to send it to rclone. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2387776/3154274) but I get the error `Failed to read password: The handle is invalid`:

```
import subprocess 
psw= input("enter psw")
psw_byte= str.encode(psw+'\n')
process = subprocess.Popen(["rclone", "listremotes"], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write(psw_byte)
process.stdin.flush()
output = process.communicate()
print(output)
```

Comment: By the by, the `shell=True` is superfluous here. You neither need nor want a shell in order to run a single command.

Comment: It seems `rclone` doesn't read its password from standard input. Many programs force a read from `/dev/tty` or some such. Maybe there is a different way to pass in a password when running scripted.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, maybe you can set the environment variable `RCLONE_CONFIG_PASS` with the password when calling the subprocess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use the `RCLONE_CONFIG_PASS` environment variable to pass the config password into rclone. See the [section in the docs about configuration encryption](https://rclone.org/docs/#configuration-encryption).

Eg

```
os.environ("RCLONE_CONFIG_PASS") = "mypassword"
```

Unix programs reading passwords tend not to be scriptable like this unless you assign a tty.

That is quite a lot of trouble though, so I recommend just setting the environment variable instead.

PS If you want to just set the enviroment for the subprocess you can do it like this: [Python subprocess/Popen with a modified environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment)

PPS I'm the author of rclone :-)

Comment: Apparently using modified environment isn't a safe way to pass the password: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53232728. As rclone doesn't read its password from standard input, is there a secure way to pass the password to rlcone via python?

Comment: As of recent `rclone` versions, it is better to use `RCLONE_PASSWORD_COMMAND` with a secrets management system like `gnome-keyring`, e.g. `export RCLONE_PASSWORD_COMMAND='secret-tool lookup service "rclone" user "calisync"'` via https://rclone.org/docs/#configuration-encryption

Answer (score 0):

This may not address the question exactly, yet, as I have not found this in this form elsewhere, here's a solution to use in `ipython` and/or `jupyter ipynb`.

Can be adapted to the meet the question:

```py
import getpass
rc_passwd = getpass.getpass()

! rclone --password-command "echo {rc_passwd}" lsd rc_remote:rc_path
```

for `rc_path` being the path in `rc_remote`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use

```
rclone obscure 'thepass'
```

and to see or use **config** file

```
rclone config file
```

insert it instead of **pass**
or possible to use [new conf file](https://rclone.org/docs/#config-config-file) by using

```
   rclone ... --config=
```

Answer (score -1):

One way around is to use `subprocess.call()` and to call a `.cmd` into which you store the `cmd` command:

in python:

```
import subprocess
cmd_path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\rclone_command.cmd"
subprocess.call([cmd_path])
```

in `rclone_command.cmd` (after rclone is done sync, you can start another python script  cf `start` ex to parse the log):

```
rclone sync  "C:\my path" "remote":"folder" --log-file "C:\Users\user\Desktop\log.log"  --log-level INFO --delete-after   --exclude "desktop.ini" 

start "" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\some other script.py"
```