# subprocess.Popen keeps on asking password for ssh-copy-id command

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I have gone through multiple threads which has similar questions ([Use subprocess to send a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387731/use-subprocess-to-send-a-password)) and have tried number of things but still i am not able to get it to work. Basically i want to push my ssh-keys to a bunch of machines and i am trying to do that with `subprocess`. But somehow `subprocess.Popen` fails to get the password and hence it gets stuck.

Below are some of things I have tried.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['ssh-copy-id', 'testbox1'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE).communicate(input=b'mypassword')
```

I have also tried supplying the password by writing to process's stdin channel like below

```
p.stdin.write(b'mypassword')
p.stdin.flush()
```

I have tried this in both python 2.7 and python and it didn't work.  I have also tried providing a linefeed as well after the password but even that didn't work. I am not sure what i am missing here.

I know people have suggested to use `Pexpect` for this but then again i am more keen in knowing why `subprocess` can't handle this.

I know there are multiple libraries like `Paramiko` and also `fabric` which handles remote connections with much ease, but i don't think that can be used in this case as i am not directly `ssh`ing to a machine and rather using `ssh-copy-id` command from my local machine

Comment: I would do some debugging first. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication/ for a decent starting place.

Comment: you could try `p.stdin.write(b'mypassword\n')`  (with a linefeed). But those silent entry methods are sometimes more low-level, and it doesn't work. Check if the command doesn't take a password as parameter (`plink` from Putty does)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i tried with linefeed as well and it didn't work.

Comment: @Rohit Give this a try? https://serverfault.com/a/306675

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` isn't reading from standard input; it's trying to read directly from the terminal.

Comment: @ChrisBeard  I don't think you are understanding the question. This is a question about python `subprocess.Popen` and not about ssh. I know how to setup passwordless auhtentication on the shell but i want to automate this process with python as i have multiple machines.

Comment: @Rohit it is on the contrary _very_ specific to `ssh`. Commands which read the typed keys from lowlevel won't react to stdin redirection.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre so there is no way to do this from python ?

Comment: it's possible but depends on the terminal. I know how to do from windows for instance.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre can you tell how you do on windows ? I mean what's the way to read from terminal with Popen ?

Comment: sending key events maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events-in-python

Comment: @Rohit If you look at sshpass, like the serfault link shows, you won't need to enter a password...

Comment: @ChrisBeard I know about sshpass but that is not what i want to do. Also sshpass does not come shipped with the OS you have to install it to use it. Finally ssh pass is a solution to pass the password to ssh related through shell, my question was very specific to a python module.

Answer (score 1):

It seemed it was way to tricky to be handled with `subprocess` and hence i had to `pexpect` to solve this and it worked in first go.

```
import pexpect
from getpass import getpass

pwd = getpass("password: ")

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh-copy-id testbox1')
child.expect('.*ssword.*:')
child.sendline(pwd)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF, timeout=None)
cmd_show_data = child.before
cmd_output = cmd_show_data.split('\r\n')
for data in cmd_output:
    print data
```

Comment: good call. Edited your question title for future readers/searchers.