# How can I enter a password in a sudo command powered by a subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run this command `sudo nmap -sP -n` with python subprocess library, my goal is creating script when I run the command the script will read the password from a file and add it to the subprocess and execute the command. The problem is that I allways have to write password to execute the command.

I have tried this, but it did not work for me.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "nmap", "-sP", "-n", network], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(bytes("Mypassword", "utf-8"))
```

I found some solutions here [Use subprocess to send a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387731/use-subprocess-to-send-a-password), I tried all of them but it did not work for me. Any idea how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sudo with Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045593/using-sudo-with-python-script)

Comment: @OlvinRoght I have tried this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sudo man page specifies:

```
 -S, --stdin
             Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the stan‐
             dard input instead of using the terminal device.  The password must be fol‐
             lowed by a newline character.
```

Running the following code should fix your issue:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "-S", "cmd"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write("password\n")
```

Obviously, make sure you give the right password or this won't work. Also, don't forget to add `\n` at the end.

As an alternative, you can run [nmap as an unprivileged user](https://secwiki.org/w/Running_nmap_as_an_unprivileged_user). This will allow you to use `nmap --privileged ...` which doesn't require a password. As specified in the link though, make sure you understand the security concerns to make sure it isn't an issue for your use case.