# Passing a password to Python subprocess

Tags: python, homebrew

I am trying to install a few programs with Homebrew as a Python subprocess.

My code looks like this:

```
from subprocess import call
call(f"brew cask install {brew_command} --force", shell=True)
```

Everything works fine but I can't find how to pass my password to this process.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can provide the password just by writing it in the `stdin` stream of the subprocess

Comment: If it's running sudo, passing to stdin won't work as the prompt is going direct to the TTY.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use subprocess to send a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387731/use-subprocess-to-send-a-password)

Comment: @Victor, btw, from a security perspective, be aware that this lets someone run any command they want, not just `brew install` commands. If someone tells your script written with this code to install a package named `</dev/null & echo "$(cat)"`, for that matter, they can capture any password or other content you might have tried to send to the stdin of `brew`.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using [`nix`](https://nixos.org/nix) instead of `brew` for any kind of case where software is installing its own dependencies -- not only is the security model more effective, but Nix installs each component it builds or downloads in a separate location, so that software isn't put into the PATH for users or projects that don't need it; this also means you can have multiple incompatible versions of the same tool or library installed at the same time without conflict.

Comment: ...and even if you do stick with `brew`, safer to rewrite your command to not need `shell=True`.